# Using Post Meta in permalink in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a post meta "link" for each post and I want to make the permalink "link/%link%". For example, if the "link" for a post is http://google.com, then I want to access the post at http://myblog.com/link/http://google.com.

Is this possible using WordPress? I don't mind modifying the core files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should have a look at this page :

http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/wordpress-permalink-add